# How to use ipython without installing in every virtualenv?

Tags: ipython, virtualenv

**Background**

I use Anaconda's IPython on my mac and it's a great tool for data exploration and debugging.  However, when I wish to use IPython for my programs that require virtualenv (e.g. a Django web app), I don't want to have to reinstall IPython every time.

**Question**

Is there a way to use my local IPython while also using the rest of my virtualenv packages?  (i.e. just make IPython the exception to virtualenv packages so that the local IPython setup is available no matter what)  If so, how would you do this on a mac?  My guess is that it would be some nifty `.bash_profile` changes, but my limited knowledge with it hasn't been fruitful.  Thanks.

**Example Usage**

Right now if I'm debugging a program, I'd use the following:

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()  # insert this to pause program and explore at command line
```

This would bring it to the command line (that I wish was IPython)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a module in your local Python and not in the virtualenv, it will still be available in the virtualenv. Unless you shadow it with another virtualenv version. Did you try to launch your local IPython from a running virtualenv that didn't have an IPython? It should work.

Comment: In my Django app (using virtualenv without IPython installed) I tried to import IPython in my code, but it gave me the 'ImportError: No module named IPython' (even though I have IPython installed on my local environment).

Comment: Can you import it when you are outside your virtualenv? It sounds like your main python is not in the python path.

Comment: Yeah, when I'm outside my virtualenv, I can run a program with the code 'import IPython'.  However, I can't import it when I'm in my virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

Will, I assume you are using Anaconda's "conda" package manager? (Which combines the features of pip and virtualenv). If so you should be aware that many parts of it does not work completely like the tools it is replacing. E.g. if you are using conda create -n myenv  to create your virtual environment, this is different from the "normal" virtualenv in a number of ways. In particular, there is no "global/default" packages: Even the default installation is essentially an environment ("root") like all other environments.

To obtain the usual virtualenv behavior, you can create your environments by cloning the root environment: conda create -n myenv --clone root. However, unlike for regular virtualenv, if you make changes to the default installation (the "root" environment in conda) these changes are not reflected in the environments that were created by cloning the root environment.

An alternative to cloning the root is to keep an updated list of "default packages" that you want to be available in new environments. This is managed by the create_default_packages option in the condarc file.

In summary: Don't treat your conda environments like regular python virtualenvs - even though they appear deceptively similar in many regards. Hopefully at some point the two implementations will converge.